# Как получить больше 1000 людей, лайкнувших пост, через VK API?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, like

Пытаюсь получить всех пользователей, кто поставил лайк под записью, через `likes.getList`. Но есть ограничение: получить разом можно только 1000 человек. А как получить всех пользователей, если таковых является, например, 3500?

Вот так я получаю список первой 1000 лайкнувших:

```
$res = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?t‌​ype=post&owner_id=-1‌​111&item_id=111&exte‌​nded=1&count=1000&of‌​fset=0'); 
$resp = json_decode($res, true); 
foreach($resp['response']['items'] as $val) { 
    echo $val['first_name'] . "<br>\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Использовать цикл?

Comment: Я тоже об этом думала, но не знаю как правильно реализовать.

Comment: Параметр `offset` используйте.

Comment: Напишите код того, что есть, можно будет посмотреть и помочь

Comment: Вот так, я получаю список первой 1000 лайкнувших `$res = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=post&owner_id=-1111&item_id=111&extended=1&count=1000&offset=0');
$resp = json_decode($res, true);
foreach($resp['response']['items'] as $val)
{
    echo $val['first_name'] . "<br>\n";
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Небольшая функция, которая работает рекурсивно, каждый раз смещая параметр `offset` на нужную величину (на `offset` в запросе + количество уже выбранных юзеров `count`) пока не придет пустой ответ. Это значит, что пора обрывать рекурсию.

Однако может еще прийти ответ `error` вместо `response`. Но эта обработка на вашей совести))

Еще также указывайте версию API, а то может вернуть не те данные, которые ожидаете или вообще ошибку вернуть.

```
$count = 1000;
$offset = 0;
$apiVersion = 5.60;
$result = [];

getLikesData($result, $count, $offset, $apiVersion);

function getLikesData(&$output, $count, $offset, $apiVersion) { 
    $query = 'https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=post&owner_id=-1‌​111&item_id=111&extended=1&friends_only=0&v='.$apiVersion.'&count='.$count.'&offset='.$offset;
    $resp = json_decode(file_get_contents($query), true);

    if (!$resp['response'])
        return;

    $items = $resp['response']['items'];

    if (empty($items))          
        return; 

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $output[] = $item;
    }

    getLikesData($output, $count, $offset + $count, $apiVersion);
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

В функции находится цикл для заполнения результирующего массива по порядку. Если вместо этого воспользоваться `array_push`, то будет отрабатывать быстрее. Однако в результирующем наборе будет массив массивов.

Это я к чему... Выбирайте что нужно: меньшая скорость, но по порядку или большая скорость, но потом при выводе придется организовывать двойной цикл.

Comment: @Eva_m В функции находится цикл для заполнения результирующего массива по порядку. Если вместо этого воспользоваться `array_push`, то будет отрабатывать быстрее. Однако в результирующем наборе будет массив массивов. Соответственно выбирайте что нужно: меньшая скорость, но по порядку или большая скорость, но потом при выводе придется организовывать двойной цикл..................Если все сработало/сработает можете галку поставить напротив ответа, чтоб закрыть вопрос и он не болтался

Answer (score 1):

Схематично (параметр `offset` [описан в документации](https://vk.com/dev/likes.getList)):

```
offset = 0;
while( likes.getList(type, owner_id, item_id, count, offset) != ERROR )
{
    users = [сколько_юзеров_получили];
    if( users == 0 ) 
    {
        /* всё, больше юзеров нет */
        break;
    }
    offset += users;
}
```

Comment: Можете помочь внедрить это в код выше?